# I can't find TempData in System.web.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

as the tittle i can't find TempData in System.Web.mvc.
Here is the picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo7OD.jpg

For more information, I deleted some references due to  not-working open source  like CKeditor,.. I am wondering if I deleted somthing important and how to check it. Thanks for your support

Comment: `TermpData` is a *property* of type `TempDataDictionary` on your controller.  `TempData` is not a class.

Comment: OMG TKS for your comment, I realized that I had wrote the code outsire the controller. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

TempData is also a dictionary derived from TempDataDictionary class. You can follow my sample:

```
TempData["Exam"] = "Hello world";
```

Comment: How does this explain why it can't be found in that namespace?  OP isn't asking how to use it, he's asking *where it is*.